# Does taking a process' memory dump cause all threads in the process to halt?

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, dump, memory-dump

If I took a memory dump of a normally running process that hadn't crashed using any of the debug diagnostics tools like DebugDiag or even using simply the Task Manager on Windows, would all threads in the process come to a halt during the time the memory dump is being taken and written to file?

I am assuming they do because that's what would make most sense. Just confirming.

Comment: Why does it matter? Are you concerned something might be holding a global lock or just curious?

Comment: I asked because I am thinking along these lines. Let's say I fire off my .NET process in the Visual Studio debugger (by hitting F5) and I step through the code and while I am debugging it this way, I reach a point where the code does a large amount of file I/O caching large amounts of data from the file in-memory. This is the time I'd like to take a memory dump. I could just do `GC.GetTotalMemory` but I'd like to take the memory dump for post-mortem. But I'd like to make sure that while the memory dump is being written, the thread that's involved in the caching of data doesn't finish.

Comment: yes, [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360(v=vs.85).aspx) internally call [SuspendThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345(v=vs.85).aspx) for every thread in process

Comment: @RbMm Thank you.